# stroustrup ppp chapter 8 drill headers

Tags: c++

For those of you that have read and done the drills from stroustrup's "programming principles and practice using c++" I am having trouble doing the first part of the chapter 8 drill. The main problem I have with this part is towards the end of the question where it states "On Windows, you need to have both **use.cpp** and **my.cpp** in a project and use **{ char cc; cin>>cc; }** in **use.cpp** to be able to see your output." If we aren't allowed **std_lib_facilities.h** for **use.cpp** how do we make this happen?
Also what exactly does it mean when it says "On Windows, you need to have both **use.cpp** and **my.cpp** in a project"? Let me know if I'm looking to deeply into this.

> Create three files: **my.h**, **my.cpp**, and **use.cpp**. The header file **my.h** contains
>
> > **extern int foo;**
> > **void print_foo();**
> > **void print(int);**
>
> The source code file **my.cpp** which **#include**
> **my.h** and **std_lib_facilities.h**, defines **print_foo()** to print the value of foo using **cout**, and **print(int i)** to print the value of **i** using **cout**.
> The source code file **use.cpp** that will **#include**  **my.h**, defines **main()** to set set the value of **foo** to **7** and print it using **print_foo()**, and to print the value 99 using **print()**. Note that **use.cpp** does not **#include**  **std_lib_facilities.h** as it doesn't directly use any of those facilities.
> Get these files complied and run. On Windows, you need to have both **use.cpp** and **my.cpp** in a project and use **{ char cc; cin>>cc; }** in **use.cpp** to be able to see your output.

Comment: Hey, I know this is an old post, but did you ever figure out the problem? I had problems even getting the "std_lib_facilities.h" to work, as described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/f199ww/how_to_include_files_in_your_projects_root/

But now I'm having trouble on this same exercise getting the my.cpp to recognize its headers properly.

Comment: Instead of this, in Visual Studio, simply go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General. There you uncheck "Automatically close the console when debugging stops". *That* is the right solution to all these hacks that people keep teaching new developers :(

Answer (score 1):

```
{ char cc; cin>>cc; }
```

Is for reading a character from standard input (**waiting** for input). In VS, and other IDEs, you need to do this just to see the output of the program otherwise the cmd window will close too fast to read the output. You don't need `std_lib_facilities.h`, just `include <iostream>` and write the code above at the end of the `main` function.

> Get these files complied and run. On Windows, you need to have both
>   use.cpp and my.cpp in a project and use { char cc; cin>>cc; } in
>   use.cpp to be able to see your output.

To compile on windows, in VS or some other IDE, you need to include both source files. On linux you need both too, however, the compilation procedure (makefile or g++) explicitly requires these files so for windows these files are emphasized.

Comment: For me, it says `undefined reference to 'foo'`. I am using g++ compiler with c++14 standard. Is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

I was subsequently able to resolve the error on the above code.
the variable foo needs to be declared extern in both the my.h header file, and again before main() in the use.cpp file as follows. The essence of the problem is with not having a global variable which the textbook frowns on.  But this solution using one is what works.

```
//
    use.cpp
    
    #include"my.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    extern int foo = 7;
    
    void delimiter() {
        cout << " ============================================================\n";
        }

    
    int main () {
        int i = 1;
        delimiter();
        cout << " Using print_foo() to print foo which is initialized as an" << endl;
        cout << " external global variable = 7." << endl << " --> ";
        print_foo();  //7
        cout << endl;
        delimiter();
        cout << " Print the variable i = 1 using print(i)." << endl << " --> ";
        print(i);  //1
        cout << endl;
        delimiter();
        cout << " Print the value 99 using print()." << endl << " --> ";
        print(99);  //99
        cout << endl;
        delimiter();
        cout << " Print the global variable foo using print()." << endl << " --> ";
        print(foo);  //7
        cout << endl;
        cout << "  Enter any character to quit." << " -- > ";
        char cc; cin >> cc;
        return 0;
    }
//
my.cpp then becomes simply
//

    #include"my.h"
    #include"std_lib_facilities.h"
    
    void print(int i) {
        cout << i;
    }
    
    void print_foo() {
        cout << foo;
    }

//

and finally my.h is:
//

    extern int foo;
    void print_foo();
    void print(int);

//
```