# Link-time errors in VS 2013 while compiling the C++ program - B. Stroustrup's PPP using C++: Ch. 8 - Q1 Drill?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker

> **Possible duplicate:** 
>   [stroustrup ppp chapter 8 drill headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704416/stroustrup-ppp-chapter-8-drill-headers)

---

I'm learning C++ using PPP using C++ by B. Stroustrup, 1st edition. I am having trouble (**errors - LNK2001 & LNK1169**) solving this question, **Ch. 8 Drill, Q1** -

> Create three files: **my.h**, **my.cpp**, and **use.cpp**. The header file **my.h** contains
>
> > **extern int foo;** 
> >     **void print_foo();** 
> >     **void print(int);**
>
> The source code file **my.cpp #includes my.h** and **std_lib_facilities.h**, defines **print_foo()** to print the value of **foo** using **cout**, and **print(int i)** to print the value of **i** using **cout**.
>
> The source code file **use.cpp #includes my.h**, defines **main()** to set
>   the value of **foo** to **7** and print it using **print_foo()**, and to print the value of **99** using **print()**. Note that **use.cpp** does not **#include std_lib_facilities.h** as it doesn't directly use any of those facilities.
>
> Get these files compiled and run. On Windows, you need to have
>   both **use.cpp** and **my.cpp** in a project and use **{ char cc; cin>>cc; }** in **use.cpp** to be able to see your output.

---

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Here are the files I created using the question -

**my_8drill.h (my.h)**

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

**my_8drill.cpp (my.cpp)**

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "my_8drill.h"

void print_foo()
{
    cout << foo << endl;
    return;
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    return;
}
```

**use_8drill.cpp (use.cpp)**

```
#include <iostream>      // Well, the question never mentioned to add "std_lib_facilities.h", 
                         // so I added this
#include "my_8drill.h"

using std::cin;

int main()
{
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);

    char c;
    while (cin >> c)
        if (c == 'q')
            break;
}
```

But these **errors** (link errors hopefully) occurred while compiling this program -

```
1>my_8drill.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int foo" (?foo@@3HA)
1>use_8drill.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int foo" (?foo@@3HA)
1>C:\Users\I$HU\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\C++ Development\Debug\C++ Development.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Then I remembered that `extern int foo;` is only a *declaration*, not a *definition*, so I need to define it somewhere, so I replaced `extern int foo;` with `int foo;` in the header file **my.h**.

But then again after compiling, these (link) **errors** occurred -

```
1>use_8drill.obj : error LNK2005: "int foo" (?foo@@3HA) already defined in my_8drill.obj
1>C:\Users\I$HU\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\C++ Development\Debug\C++ Development.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

So from the errors, I assumed that since there are two **"my.h"** headers, one in **my.cpp** and other in **use.cpp**, so I changed back `int foo;` in **my.h** to `extern int foo;` and added `int foo;` to **use.cpp** like this -

```
#include <iostream>
int foo;            // this line is new
#include "my_8drill.h"
```

and so `foo` won't get defined twice, and the program runs fine now,

But still, these **questions** are bothering me again & again -

1. Am I correct in my approach while resolving the above-mentioned errors ?
2. (Extension to **1**) Is there anything more to know (missing details) about these errors (I'm quite positive about this) ?
3. Even if the program runs in the end, how do function-declarations in **my.h** know where their definition are (in **my.cpp**) ?
4. (Extension to **3**) How do they link up (**my.h** & **my.cpp**) with each other when I've only **#include**d `"my.h"` to **use.cpp** ?
5. How do just adding `int foo;` to **my.cpp** lets **my.h** know about the variable `foo`?

Please help me with these.

Here is the header file [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h).

Comment: In a nutshell -- avoid global variables.  Second, those errors are *linker* errors, not compiler errors.  It is the linker that is responsible for "finding" all of your definitions.  All you're telling the compiler is "hey, these variables are defined somewhere else -- trust me", and the compiler trusts you.  After compilation, the linker now looks for what you claim exists, and gives you an error if there is a problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:I know, this is taught in this chapter too but it is never told anywhere (till this chapter hopefully) how even after by not including a `.cpp` file (containing several definitions) in a similar `.h` file lets the `.h` file (containing only declarations, not definitions) know about the definitions in that `.cpp` file, it still confuses me.

Comment: When you build a program, there are 2 stages.  The first stage is compilation.  A compiler determines if your program is *syntactically* correct -- it doesn't care if those variables or functions actually exist, as long as you claim to the compiler  that they exist.  On successful compilation, the linker (which creates the final executable) takes the compiled code and **then** the search is on for those functions/variables you claim exist.  It is this phase where you are getting the errors.  The linker knows nothing about .cpp or .h files -- all it sees is object code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I get that part but I still don't understand the "thing" (or just a doubt) I mentioned in my previous comment (and in question too).

Comment: The easiest way to understand what is going on is to understand that all a header file does is "expand" in place at that point in your source code.  In other words, if you took out that `#include` for that header, and instead copy and pasted the contents of the `h` file at that spot in your cpp file, you end up with exactly what the compiler is seeing.  Don't try to think beyond that -- the reason is that is *exactly* what the compiler is compiling, no more, no less.

Comment: Okay, but how does adding the header file `my.h` to `use.cpp` lets `use.cpp` know about `my.cpp`?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know about the other .cpp file.  It is the linker that is told what modules exist that are linked together, **not** the compiler.  You have to give the linker the list of compiled modules.  Look at the errors you're getting -- again, they are *linker* errors, *not* compiler errors.  All of your source files compiled successfully.

Comment: So you mean to say that `my.cpp` includes `my.h` and linker combines object files of both `use.cpp` & `my.cpp` while linking, and so even if `use.cpp` has declarations (not definitions) from `my.h`, it knows where its definitions are (from the object file of `my.cpp`). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The linker takes the object modules and attempts to find the actual function or variable that you claim exists.  If it finds it, your're ok.  If it finds multiple definitions, you get the error (actually the linker is free to do whatever it wants if you have multiply defined symbols -- for the MS linker and most others, the default behavior is to issue an error, but this can be turned off (at your own.peril)).  If the linker can't find the symbol at all, you get an error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thanks for helping. :) BTW is there any better solution to the errors mentioned in the question, I mean instead of adding `int foo;` before `#include "my_8drill.h"` in `my_8drill.cpp`, is there any other better way to achieve the same?

Comment: All solutions to the problem you're having boil down to what you did.  One module has to have the actual definition, while the other modules have to have `extern`.  The only difference is that the other solutions make the code look "nicer", but again, it boils down to the same thing.  For example, the old C way of doing this was to toggle the `extern` keyword on or off using macros, and for the main module, `extern` keyword was turned off, while for the other modules, it was turned on.  But again, just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the `use.cpp` file, the compiler only sees the `my.h` header file and not the `my.cpp` file which contains the source code of that file.

You need to include `my.cpp` file also in your `use.cpp` program. Or you can add

```
#include "my.cpp"
```

at the end of `my.h` file.