# Linking Error due to symbol(s) not found in Bjarne Stroustrup "Programming and Practices using c++"

Tags: c++, g++, clang, linker-errors

I'm new to c++ (and compiled languages in general) and am doing the drill at the end of chapter 8 in Bjarne Stroustrup "Programming and Practices using c++" but I'm getting the following error when I try to compile the code

```
➜  Desktop g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp -o use
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      print_foo() in my-4f7853.o
      _main in use-46cb26.o
     (maybe you meant: __Z9print_foov)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've also tried using `g++ -c my.cpp use.cpp` followed by `g++ -o use.exe my.o use.o` but this gave the same error. The other approach I tried was `g++ -c use.cpp -o use.exe`, however `use.exe` produced no output when it ran. The source code files are

my.h

```
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print_int(int);
```

my.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>

void print_foo() {
  std::cout << foo << '\n';
}

void print_int(int num) {
  std::cout << num << '\n';
}
```

use.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::cout<<"DSGFSGFSG"<< '\n';
  foo = 7;
  print_foo();

  int i = 99;
  print_int(i);

}
```

I've looked at other questions that are similar (if not seemingly the same is in [Link-time errors in VS 2013 while compiling the C++ program - B. Stroustrup's PPP using C++: Ch. 8 - Q1 Drill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191942/link-time-errors-in-vs-2013-while-compiling-the-c-program-b-stroustrups-pp)) but the solutions haven't worked for me. Is the problem to do with my compilation using g++ or have I made a more fundamental error?

Comment: Please don’t post code with line numbers prefixed — they don’t really help, and they make it much harder for others to copy your code and run it themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The global variable `foo` is only *declared* in your header file.
`extern int foo;`

You also need to *define* it in `my.cpp`
`int foo;`

The declaration is a promise: "it exists somewhere".
The definition actually reserves some storage for this variable.

So your linker complains because some code relying on this
promise needs to access this missing storage.